# Fabric.js bounding box aligned with a line

Tags: fabricjs

In Fabric.js, the bounding box of a vertical line is as small as the line itself.
When the line is not vertical or horizontal, the bounding box takes more surface.

I'd like to have the bounding box always along the lines, even when the line is not vertical or horizontal.
Is there an option or a way to regenerate the bounding box with a certain angle (same angle of the lines)?

Answer (score 0):

Rotated horizontal or vertical line have bounding box along the line. You can utilize this to solve this. So, I solved this problem by redrawing the line. Draw horizontal line and then rotate it. Given `originalLine`, calculate `angle` and `length`. Then redraw line with that `angle` and `length`. Let call redrawn line `newLine`.

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    selection: true
});
const startX = 20;
const startY = 20;
const size = 20;

const originalLine = new fabric.Line([startX, startY, 100, 100], {
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: size,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
});

// Calculate angle and length for the new line
const dx = originalLine.x2 - originalLine.x1;
const dy = originalLine.y2 - originalLine.y1;
const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * (180 / Math.PI);
const length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

// create a new horizontal line, then rotate it
const newLine = new fabric.Line([startX, startY, startX + length, startY], {
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: size,
    angle: angle,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'center',
});

canvas.add(newLine);
canvas.setActiveObject(newLine);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

`originX` and `originY` of both `originalLine` and `newLine` are important. Otherwise, newly created line will be shifted a little bit. The reason for this is explained further below.

There maybe one possible problem with this. The newly created line origin is left center and you may prefer default origin top left. In that case, you can update origin and then update `top` and `left`.

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    selection: true
});
const startX = 20;
const startY = 20;
const size = 20;

const originalLine = new fabric.Line([startX, startY, 100, 100], {
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: size,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
});

// Calculate angle and length for the new line
const dx = originalLine.x2 - originalLine.x1;
const dy = originalLine.y2 - originalLine.y1;
const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * (180 / Math.PI);
const length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

// create a new horizontal line, then rotate it
const newLine = new fabric.Line([startX, startY, startX + length, startY], {
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: size,
    angle: angle,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'center',
});
// this make `tl` available
newLine.setCoords();
canvas.add(newLine);

// tl have correct values for `top` and `left`
const correct_top = newLine.lineCoords.tl.y;
const correct_left = newLine.lineCoords.tl.x;
newLine.set({
    originY: 'top',
    top: correct_top,
    left: correct_left,
})

canvas.setActiveObject(newLine);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

## More about origin

First, refer to this origin visualization. http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/origin.html

If you ignored `originX` and `originY` in earlier code, the new line will be shifted a little bit. In canvas below, red is `originalLine` and blue is redrawn line `newLine`. Circle is for visualizing start point. You can see that there is a small shift/gap between two lines even though they are drawn at same starting position.

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
    selection: true
});
const startX = 20;
const startY = 20;
const size = 20;

const originalLine = new fabric.Line([startX, startY, 100, 100], {
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: size,
});

// Calculate angle and length for the new line
const dx = originalLine.x2 - originalLine.x1;
const dy = originalLine.y2 - originalLine.y1;
const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * (180 / Math.PI);
const length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

// create a new horizontal line, then rotate it
const newLine = new fabric.Line([startX, startY, startX + length, startY], {
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: size,
    angle: angle,
});

// visualize starting point
const startPoint = new fabric.Circle({
    left: startX,
    top: startY,
    radius: 5,
    fill: 'green',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    selectable: false
});

canvas.add(newLine);
canvas.add(originalLine);
canvas.add(startPoint);
canvas.setActiveObject(originalLine);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The reason for shift is because as you can see in above canvas, for `originalLine`, there is some gap between start point and the left end of line. This issue is more apparent with bigger `strokeWidth`. So, even if `newLine` is drawn at the same start position, there will be some shift/gap.

This is why `originX` `center` `originY` `center` for `originalLine` and `originX` `left` `originY` `center` for `newLine` is needed. With those origin values, there will be no shift/gap between `originalLine` and `newLine`.